# Server rendering in python/ruby/php then attach react.js in client

Tags: php, ruby, django, reactjs, jinja2

I'd like to try react.js.

Most examples seem to suggest `server api + reactjs rendering`
or `server rendering via node/reactjs + reactjs rendering on client`

I'd like to have two templates, one server and one client because I think maintaining node+reactjs on server is a hassle and cause performance degrade.

If I render html on server with jinja2 (or whatever server template language other than reactjs), would it be possible to attach reactjs component to the rendered html?

Doesn't react add special `id` and `key` attributes to divs that are hard to create with jinja2 (or any template language) ?